# How to inline function calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, macros, higher-order-functions

I need a function `expand(fn)`, that will accept any function and return a function where all the function calls in the input function are replaced with codes of these functions.

For example, given `f` and `g` functions below:

```
function f(x) {
    console.log('f: ' + x);
}

function g(x) {
    console.log('g: ' + x);
    f(x + 1);
}
```

`expand(g)` should return such a function:

```
function anon(x) {
    console.log('g: ' + x);
    var arg1 = x + 1;
    {
        console.log('f: ' + arg1);
    }
}
```

`expand(g)` should work just as the function `g`. But `expand(g)` should not call any functions except standard JavaScript functions.

Such an `expand` function would be handy when I'm going to pass just a plain JavaScript function to a foreign sandbox and I want to be able to use my functions and other JS libraries in that function to be executed there.

I'd like to be able to expand functions with parameters, functions from external libraries and nested functions. Even recursive functions could be converted to loops but I'm not looking for that for now.

Comment: What's the difference between `anon` and `g`?  Couldn't `expand(fn)` just return `fn`?

Comment: Do you want function inlining?

Comment: @recursive `f()` in `g` is replaced with the body block of `f`.

Comment: @2426021684 I want to expand function calls inside a body with their respective bodies recursively. But I also want to pass the function parameters inside these bodies.

Comment: That sounds like you want to modify source code at runtime. That's not really possible, unless you want to use a JS parser, to some AST transformation, print the AST and `eval` the result.

Comment: @EmrehanTuzun why would want to do this? anon does the same thing as g

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009411/tool-to-automatically-inline-javascript-function-calls

Comment: @FelixKling I'm willing to start such an open source project :)

Comment: @2426021684 Because I'm going to pass this function to a foreign sandbox and I want to be able to define functions and use JS libraries in my function to be executed there.

Comment: Well, it already exists ;) (kind of) https://babeljs.io/ But usually this is done as a compile step, not at runtime. This will also easily break if `f` in your example was a closure.

Comment: You would need to write a babel plugin

Comment: @EmrehanTuzun easier to include the library in the foreign sandbox

Comment: @EmrehanTuzun: What should `expand()` do if it contains a call to a function which uses a variable from an enclosing scope?  That can't be inlined.

Comment: @2426021684 it's not possible to include libraries in Postman sandboxes, and many others.

Comment: @recursive it can pass the variable in the head of the expanded function block. If it's not available at runtime it can just throw an error.

Comment: Or maybe you want something like: http://sweetjs.org/ ... (also a compile step)

Comment: @FelixKling that makes sense. Do you know where can I start?

Comment: @pizzasynthesis, sweet.js looks, well, sweet! Have you ever written plugins for sweet or babel?